# Uso de group_concat con eagger loading en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

> Tengo que regresar en una tabla en HTML, el nombre del usuario y los
>   nombres de los posts; sin embargo tengo registrado mas de un post por
>   usuario; por lo cual requiero hacer uso de `group_concat()` para
>   meterlos en una sola celda; lo estoy intentando de este modo, pero no
>   me regresa ningún dato de la tabla posts

```
public function listado()
    {
        $data = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(namePost SEPARATOR '-') as `N`"));
        }])->get();
        return view('posts')->with(['data' => $data]);
    }
```

Se que no estoy invocando a la tabla posts, pero no se como hacerlo; agradecería su ayuda

En SQL lo hago de esta manera y me es funcional

```
MariaDB [blog]> select users.nameUser, GROUP_CONCAT(posts.namePost) AS N
    -> FROM users
    -> JOIN posts
    -> ON users.id = posts.user_id
    -> GROUP BY users.nameUser;
```

Hago la aclaración que dentro de Eloquent estoy haciendo uso de eagger loading; por que trabaja con las relaciones `hasMany()` y `belongsTo()`

> El resultado que busco obtener es algo asi

```
+----------+---------------+
| nameUser | N             |
+----------+---------------+
| alfa     | PHP 7,MySQL 8 |
| beta     | HTML 5        |
+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi propia publicación, opté por no hacerlo con `eagger loading` y las `relaciones` que ofrece Laravel; entonces mezclé el ORM y funciones de Fluent el query Builder

El resultado de la consulta que obtuve es la siguiente

```
$data = User::select('users.nameUser')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(namePost) AS Listado')
    ->join('posts', 'users.id', '=', posts.user_id)
    ->groupBy('nameUser')
    ->get();
```

El método `selectRaw()` me permite ejecutar funciones SQL que no existen dentro del ORM de forma nativa

> El método SelectRaw() puede ser utilizado en lugar de DB::Raw() para
>   llevar a acabo la creación de consultas en lenguaje SQL
>   [referencia](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Hola bro estoy intentado hacer algo similar pero no doy con el resultado. si me quieres colaborar este es el link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/554098/7101