# Mostrar varios valores en una columna (GROUP_CONCAT) con varias relaciones

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Necesito mostrar en una columna todos los artículos que ha comprado un cliente en una venta, como ejemplo esto es lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las tabla que estan relacionas para obtener los nombres del articulo y los campos que necesito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando armar la consulta con la función `GROUP_CONCAT` pero no lo he logrado que muestre el nombre de los articulos, con esta consulta solo me trae los id.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(articulo_id) FROM detalle_ventas
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realice esta consulta pero no obtengo lo que quiero

```
SELECT  v.num_comprobante, CONCAT(p.nombre,' ',p.apellido) AS cliente, v.fecha, GROUP_CONCAT(a.nombre) AS articulos,
  FORMAT(v.total,0) AS total, u.nombre AS cajero,v.estado FROM ventas v  
    INNER JOIN personas p ON
    v.persona_id=p.id
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON
    v.id=d.venta_id
    INNER JOIN articulos a ON
    d.articulo_id=a.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON
    v.`user_id`=u.`id`
    GROUP BY v.id,a.nombre
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo intenten con este:

```
SELECT  ventas.num_comprobante, CONCAT(personas.nombre,' ',personas.apellido) AS cliente, ventas.fecha, detalle_ventas.id, GROUP_CONCAT(articulos.nombre) AS articulos
 FROM ventas   
    INNER JOIN personas ON
    ventas.persona_id=personas.id
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas ON
    ventas.id=detalle_ventas.venta_id
    INNER JOIN articulos ON
    detalle_ventas.articulo_id=articulos.id
GROUP BY detalle_ventas.articulo_id,articulos.nombre
```

Pero me arroja este error:

```
Error Code: 1055
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ferreteria.ventas.num_comprobante' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

esta es la estructura de la bd de datos

```
/*
SQLyog Ultimate v13.1.1 (64 bit)
MySQL - 5.7.33 : Database - ferreteria
*********************************************************************
*/

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`ferreteria` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci */;

USE `ferreteria`;

/*Table structure for table `articulos` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articulos`;

CREATE TABLE `articulos` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `imagen` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `articulos_nombre_index` (`nombre`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


/*Table structure for table `detalle_ventas` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `detalle_ventas`;

CREATE TABLE `detalle_ventas` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cantidad` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  `venta_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `articulo_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `detalle_ventas_articulo_id_foreign` (`articulo_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_ventas_articulo_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`articulo_id`) REFERENCES `articulos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `detalle_ventas_venta_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`venta_id`) REFERENCES `ventas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `personas`;

CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` char(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `celular` char(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo_documento_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `personas_tipo_documento_id_foreign` (`tipo_documento_id`),
  KEY `personas_apellido_index` (`apellido`),
  CONSTRAINT `personas_tipo_documento_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo_documento_id`) REFERENCES `tipo_documentos` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


/*Table structure for table `tipo_documentos` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tipo_documentos`;

CREATE TABLE `tipo_documentos` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` char(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` char(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tipo_documentos_numero_index` (`numero`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*Table structure for table `users` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `acceso` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_acceso_unique` (`acceso`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*Table structure for table `ventas` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ventas`;

CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nota` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  `num_comprobante` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `impuesto` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persona_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ventas_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `ventas_persona_id_foreign` (`persona_id`),
  KEY `ventas_fecha_index` (`fecha`),
  CONSTRAINT `ventas_persona_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `ventas_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Comment: Todas aquellas columnas que pudieran tener más de una fila de resultados deben ser puestas en el `GROUP BY`,  o deben ser puestas en una función de agregación. En este caso, intenta modificar el grupo de este modo: `GROUP BY detalle_ventas.articulo_id,articulos.nombre,ventas.num_comprobante`

Comment: ¿Nos pasas el dataset en SQL para probar tus consultas?

Comment: @A.Cedano sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: @DavidJP disculpa me puedes guiar el proceso para poder compartir la bd de datos por este medio

Comment: Con `GROUP BY v.id` debe ser suficiente, pero el total debería ser: `sum(d.cantidad*d.precio) AS total`.

Comment: NO es el mismo error. En mi comentario te dije que TODAS las columnas que pudieran tener más de una fila de resultados deben ser puestas en el `GROUP BY` o en una función de agregación. El nuevo error habla de OTRA columna con el mismo problema de la anterior, entonces pon TAMBIÈN esa columna en el `GROUP BY`. Lo que debes entender es que, cuando hay más de un posible resultado el SGBD debe saber qué hacer con él, si agrupar, si sumar, si mandar el mayor, si mandar el menor, etc. Es preciso entender eso cuando trabajas con `GROUP BY` o te pasarás horas/días rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: @Juanzu Desde http://localhost/phpmyadmin, seleccionas la base de datos y tienes una opción de exportar. Copias el contenido del fichero descargado modificando tu pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si tienes razón, igual agregue todos al GROUP BY y me trae los artículos en individual registro.

Comment: @DavidJP listo yo agrege el sql de las tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que ésta es la consulta que estás buscando:

```
SELECT num_comprobante,personas.nombre cliente,
  fecha,articulos,c1.total,users.nombre cajero,ventas.estado
  FROM ventas
  JOIN (
    SELECT venta_id,GROUP_CONCAT(a.nombre)  articulos,
      ROUND(SUM(cantidad*precio),2) total
      FROM detalle_ventas
      JOIN articulos a ON a.id=articulo_id
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 ON ventas.id=venta_id
  JOIN personas ON personas.id=persona_id
  JOIN users ON users.id=user_id;
```

Como no me consta que actualices el campo `ventas.total` lo he calculado a partir del `detalle_ventas`. He asumido que el cajero estará en `users`, básicamente por la contraseña, y el cliente en `personas`.

Una lástima que no hubieras aportado los datos para comprobar alguno de los resultados que esperabas obtener.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar convenientemente la respuesta.

Comment: Si me esta agrupando pero no me esta pintando la columna de los artículos

Comment: Perdona, me la había saltado :) Ya la tienes